# How to set and get cookie?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this function but problem is that i never get first part, its like there is no cookie.Any suggestion how i can fix this?

```
  public function downvote(Request $request){

       $comment_id = $request->comment_id;
      if(!Cookie::has('vote_' + $comment_id)){
         Cookie::forever('vote_' + $comment_id, $comment_id);
         return response()->json(['already_voted' => true],200);
      }
      else{
        $comment = ArticleComments::findOrFail($comment_id);
        $comment->downvotes -= 1;
        $comment->save();
        return response()->json(['downvote_value' => $comment->downvotes],200);

      }
    }
```

Comment: Try this one: `$request->cookie('name');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a cooking and send it with your response:

```
public function downvote(Request $request)
{
    $comment_id = $request->comment_id;
    $cookie_id = 'vote_' + $comment_id;

    if ($request->cookie($cookie_id)) {
        return response()->json(['already_voted' => true], 200)
    } else {
        $comment = ArticleComments::findOrFail($comment_id);

        $comment->downvotes -= 1;

        $comment->save();

        return response()
                ->json(['downvote_value' => $comment->downvotes],200)
                ->cookie(Cookie::forever($cookie_id, $comment_id));
    }
}
```

Check the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#cookies